# Android SQLite syntax error near "," On API 21<

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:**

> SELECT transaction_detail_outlet_id  FROM   order_details
> LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts
> ON order_details.account_id = accounts._id
> AND accounts.account_name = 'asset1andriodx'
> LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse_skunits_inventory
> ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id =
> warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_id
> AND order_details.transaction_detail_from_warehouse_id =
> warehouse_skunits_inventory.warehouse_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *
> FROM   warehouse_skunits_pricing
> WHERE  ( warehouse_id, skunit_id, skunit_batch_id,
> skunit_price_priority ) IN (
> SELECT
> warehouse_id,
> skunit_id,
> skunit_batch_id,
> Max(skunit_price_priority) AS
> skunit_price_priority
> FROM
> warehouse_skunits_pricing
> GROUP
> BY warehouse_id,
> skunit_id,
> skunit_batch_id)) AS
> warehouse_skunits_pricing
> ON
> order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id =
> warehouse_skunits_pricing.skunit_id
> AND order_details.transaction_detail_from_warehouse_id =
> warehouse_skunits_pricing.warehouse_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN skunits
> ON
> order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = skunits.skunit_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN discounts
> ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id =
> discounts.discount_skunit_id
> AND order_details.transaction_detail_outlet_id =
> discounts.discount_outlet_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN form_type
> ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id =
> form_type.form_type_type_id
> AND form_type.form_type_form_type = 'skunits_order'
> LEFT OUTER JOIN outlet_targets
> ON order_details.transaction_detail_outlet_id =
> outlet_targets.outlet_targets_outlet_id
> AND order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id =
> outlet_targets.outlet_targets_skunit_id
> LEFT OUTER JOIN batches
> ON  warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_id = batches.batch_skunit_id  AND
> warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_batch_id = batches.batch_id  WHERE  ( transaction_detail_draft = '0'
> OR transaction_detail_draft = '2' )

Android is giving error once we execute above mentioned query in android version < 21. Same query works in higher android device.

In app earlier we used **sqlcipher** which we removed now, and it turns out that **sqlcipher** have it's own syntax formatting so it didn't cause any issue for older devices.

Is sqlite have different syntax for different version of android. Because the sqlite lib is already updated(**"androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.1.0"**) and it should support db engine of older device as well.(or how does it works based on android version)

I have updated all double quoted "string" query to 'single' quotes, this is one syntax change i found while experimenting.

Is there any simple solution to support the same syntax in all android devices?

Comment: Did you check what is the version of SQLite used in android version < 21? Execute `select sqlite_version();` to find out.

Comment: It is 3.8 as mentioned in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary

Answer (score 1):

[Row Values](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) are supported in SQLite since version 3.15.0.
This is the part of your code that uses Row Values:

```
WHERE (warehouse_id, skunit_id, skunit_batch_id, skunit_price_priority ) IN (....)
```

A workaround would be to use a join:

```
SELECT transaction_detail_outlet_id 
FROM order_details 
LEFT OUTER JOIN accounts 
     ON order_details.account_id = accounts._id 
     AND accounts.account_name = 'asset1andriodx' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN warehouse_skunits_inventory 
     ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_id 
     AND order_details.transaction_detail_from_warehouse_id = warehouse_skunits_inventory.warehouse_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT w.* 
  FROM warehouse_skunits_pricing w
  INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT warehouse_id, skunit_id, skunit_batch_id, Max(skunit_price_priority) AS skunit_price_priority 
    FROM warehouse_skunits_pricing 
    GROUP BY warehouse_id, skunit_id, skunit_batch_id
  ) t 
  ON t.warehouse_id = w.warehouse_id AND t.skunit_id = w.skunit_id AND t.skunit_batch_id = w.skunit_batch_id AND t.skunit_price_priority = w.skunit_price_priority
) AS warehouse_skunits_pricing 
      ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = warehouse_skunits_pricing.skunit_id 
      AND order_details.transaction_detail_from_warehouse_id = warehouse_skunits_pricing.warehouse_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN skunits 
     ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = skunits.skunit_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN discounts 
     ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = discounts.discount_skunit_id 
     AND order_details.transaction_detail_outlet_id = discounts.discount_outlet_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN form_type 
     ON order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = form_type.form_type_type_id 
     AND form_type.form_type_form_type = 'skunits_order' 
LEFT OUTER JOIN outlet_targets 
     ON order_details.transaction_detail_outlet_id = outlet_targets.outlet_targets_outlet_id 
     AND order_details.transaction_detail_skunit_id = outlet_targets.outlet_targets_skunit_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN batches 
     ON warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_id = batches.batch_skunit_id 
     AND warehouse_skunits_inventory.skunit_batch_id = batches.batch_id 
WHERE (transaction_detail_draft = '0' OR transaction_detail_draft = '2')
```

I hope I have no typos.

Comment: Hi forpas.. thanks for the quick feedback. The issue is not with this single query. In our app we have many different queries which started throwing the mentioned error. I am looking for a reason why this is not working in sqlite 3.8 (android 5 <) and same syntax is working in above version. The code base is huge and will be long process if I change the all the queries.

Comment: The mentioned query is just one sample.

Comment: My answer is about the code you posted in your question.

Comment: upvote for some suggestion, indeed this individual query is fixed after making changes you suggested.

Comment: To answer also your question *Is there any simple solution to support the same syntax in all android devices?* No, there isn't. You must use only features of SQLite supported by the lowest version of the devices that your app will run.